# How to set Icon and make application executable on MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, build

This is my workflow file. On windows there is icon and application is executable. But with macos i have problems

`name: Build-All-Platforms

on:
push:
branches: [ "main" ]
workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
build:
strategy:
fail-fast: false
matrix:
include:
- os: ubuntu-latest
python-version: 3.9
container: "python:3.9-buster"
- os: windows-latest
python-version: 3.x
- os: macos-latest
python-version: 3.x

```
runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
container: ${{ matrix.container }}

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - name: Setup Python
    if: ${{ !matrix.container }} # Use setup-python only if not in the container
    uses: actions/setup-python@v2
    with:
      python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}

  - name: Upgrade pip (Windows & macOS)
    if: ${{ !matrix.container }} # Run only if not in the container
    run: |
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  - name: Upgrade pip (Ubuntu)
    if: ${{ matrix.container }} # Run only in the container
    run: |
      pip install --upgrade pip
  - name: Install System Dependencies (Ubuntu)
    if: ${{ matrix.container }} # Run only in the container
    run: |
      apt-get update
      apt-get install -y python3-tk gettext tcl-thread tk tk-dev tcl libxcb-xinerama0
  - name: Install Pyinstaller Dependencies
    run: |
      pip install pyinstaller
  - name: Install Package Dependencies
    run: |
      pip install -r requirements.txt
  - name: Build Executable
    run: |
      pyinstaller --onefile --icon=icons.ico app.py
  - name: Set Execution Permissions (Linux)
    if: runner.os == 'Linux'
    run: chmod +x dist/*

  - name: Set Execution Permissions (macOS)
    if: runner.os == 'macOS'
    run: chmod +x dist/*

  - name: Upload Artifacts
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: ${{ runner.os }} Build
      node-version: 16
      path: |
        dist/*`
```

Thats how I tried to set icon

`pyinstaller --onefile --icon=icons.ico app.py`

This how I tried to make app executable for mac
`  - name: Set Execution Permissions (macOS)
if: runner.os == 'macOS'
run: chmod +x dist/*

```
  - name: Upload Artifacts
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: ${{ runner.os }} Build
      node-version: 16
      path: |
        dist/*``
```